# Can Articy Draft be used to write a book?

Tags: software, tools, articy-draft

I recently bought Articy Draft to catalog my writing endeavours. It seems good for writing scripts, but what about writing a book?

Reference: http://www.nevigo.com/en/articydraft/overview/

I'm planning writing a novel using this tool. It's built primarily for game design (scripts and dialogs included). It's very useful for creating your universe's database and you can relate database items (like characters) inside your scripts, so you know when/where they are used. I thought it would be a good tool for coherence's sake.

Answer (score 5):

Answer from Kai Rosenkranz "[Nevigo Developer](http://www.nevigo.com/en/articydraft/overview/)" in the Steam thread [Articy: Just for games?](http://steamcommunity.com/app/230780/discussions/0/846959520943948195/)

> Thanks for your interest. Between 10 and 20 percent of our customers use articy:draft for other purposes than designing games, like novelists, screenwriters, and instructional designers (for game-based training, ...ok, that may count as game design :) ).

Based on Kai's comment, I guess then **it's pretty safe to affirm that Articy Draft can be used to write a book**.

But, by my first impressions, I would say Articy is much better as a resource tool than as a writing tool. It's also not exactly cheap.

This answer would not be complete if I didn't say [Scrivener](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php) -- *for example* -- for one third of the price, will also allow you to manage resources -- *places, characters, concepts* -- in a very effective way and is much more focused on writing.

Comment: Great answer, +1. Are there any other similar resources like Scrivener that you're aware of?

Comment: Thanks. [Writer's Cafè](http://writerscafe.co.uk/) is also a great tool, and costs more or less the same as Scrivener. The downside is Scrivener has a nice and integrated system of managing the scenes and chapter texts, while Writer's Cafè uses an external editor. It's a matter of personal taste to choose one or the other, imo.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean; much better to have it all self contained. I'll try Scrivener then, thanks @Psicofrenia

Comment: @CLockeWork I'll second Scrivener; it's very flexible and allows you to keep multiple kinds of media all in one place. It's designed for writing (prose, screenplays) and allows you to export as other formats easily.

Comment: Excellent, just what I'm looking for (need a solid way to manage my world's lore) Thanks @LaurenIpsum

Comment: @CLockeWork if you search for "Scrivener" on Writers you'll find a lot of people singing its praises in detail.